# why --- (3 dashes/hyphen) in yaml file?

Tags: yaml

So I just started using `YAML` file instead of `application.properties` as it is more readable. I see in `YAML` files they start with `---`. I googled and found the below explanation.

> YAML uses three dashes (“---”) to separate directives from document
>   content. This also serves to signal the start of a document if no
>   directives are present.

Also, I tried a sample without `---` and understood that it is not mandatory to have them.

I think I don't have a clear understanding of `directive` and `document`. Can anyone please explain with a simple example?

Comment: @lexicore I checked the docs before I tried an example. But I did not get a clear understanding and I thought I would understand better if someone explained. I am sorry if it appeared very basic, FYI I am only a beginner.

Answer (score 283, accepted):

As you already found out, the three dashes `---` are used to **signal the start of a document**, i.e.:

1. To signal the document start **after directives**, i.e., `%YAML` or `%TAG` lines according to the current spec. For example:

   ```
   %YAML 1.2
   %TAG !foo! !foo-types/
   ---
   myKey: myValue
   ```
2. To signal the document start when you have **multiple yaml documents in the same stream**,  e.g., a yaml file:

   ```
   doc 1
   ---
   doc 2
   ```

   If doc 2 has some preceding directives, then we have to use three dots `...` to indicate the end of doc 1 (and the start of potential directives preceding doc 2) to the parser. For example:

   ```
   doc 1
   ...
   %TAG !bar! !bar-types/
   ---
   doc 2
   ```

The spec is good for yaml parser implementers. However, I find [this article](https://camel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yamlref.html) easier to read from a user perspective.

Comment: I read production rule 211 in the YAML 1.2 spec in such a way that you don't need a document-end-indicator even if you have directives in the following document, the only thing required in that case is that you have an end-of-directives indicator (at the beginning of the `l-explicit-document`).

Comment: My understanding on the three dots usage is based on this sentence of [the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801681): **"If a document is not terminated by a document end marker line, then the following document must begin with a directives end marker line. "**


Requiring a document to begin with the directives end marker `---` would mean no directives are allowed for that document. So if doc 2 has directives, doc 1 must be terminated with the document end marker `...`.

Comment: In fact, the [definition of l-explicit-document](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2801301) forbids directives for it: **"An explicit document begins with an explicit directives end marker line but no directives."**

Comment: Rule 211 explicitly has the directives outside of the l-explicit-document, and I am not sure if your quoting of the text even contradicts that. In any case the Python YAML parsers do implement it that way (i.e. you don't need an explicit end-of-document indicator before the next documents directives).

Comment: I don't see Rule 211 allowing directives preceding `l-explicit-document`. The expression `l-document-prefix*` does not contain directives. I am not familiar with the Python Yaml parser, but an interesting question would be whether it just silently skips the directives, if they are not preceded by the dots.

Comment: This is also good as a brief intro: https://gettaurus.org/docs/YAMLTutorial/

Comment: Did the people designing YAML ever stop to think whether or not they should implement this?

Comment: When I read it using devops pipeline, it is one object with both sections merged

Answer (score 90):

It's not mandatory to have them if you do not begin your `YAML` with a directive. If it's the case, you should use them.

Let's take a look at the documentation

> **3.2.3.4. Directives**
>
> Each document may be associated with a set of directives. A directive has a name and an optional sequence of
>   parameters. **Directives are instructions to the YAML processor, and
>   like all other presentation details are not reflected in the YAML
>   serialization tree or representation graph**. This version of YAML
>   defines a two directives, “YAML” and “TAG”. All other directives are
>   reserved for future versions of YAML.

One example of this can also be found [**in the documentation**](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#YAML%20directive/) for directive `YAML`

```
%YAML 1.2 # Attempt parsing
           # with a warning
---
"foo"
```