# Ambiguous warning : "WARN[0064] image [gcr.io/wired-benefit-XXXXX/demoapp] is not used by the deployment"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, skaffold

#### Expected behavior

Stated warning should NOT be displayed.

#### Actual behavior

Every time I make a change and trigger a re-deployment, I get an error like:

> WARN[0064] image [gcr.io/wired-benefit-XXXXX/demoapp] is not used by the deployment

Yet the image is modified with the updated change, so I'm not sure what the error is indicating,

#### Information

- Skaffold version: version... v1.15.0
- Operating system: ... MacOS Catilina 10.15.16
- Contents of skaffold.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta8
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: demoapp
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: gcr.io/wired-benefit-293406/demoapp
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8*.yml
```

Content of K8s manifests :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demoapp
  name: demoapp
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demoapp
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demoapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/wired-benefit-293406/demoapp
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: demoapp
      restartPolicy: Always

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demoapp
  name: demoapp-svc
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: demoapp
  type: LoadBalancer

apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: demoapp
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: demoapp
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
```

#### Steps to reproduce the behavior

1. a very basic starter demo app
2. `skaffold dev`
3. Any change ... docker build is successful by skaffold and even pushing to registry

But, changes are not being reflected. Could be tag related problem. When I manually set the image name to latest for the deployment, then app change works.

Comment: Does your `K8S manifests` is a single file with `Deployment`, `Service` and `HPA` inside of it? I ran exactly as you've pasted it (encountered same warning) and it lacked the `---` in between the resources. Please tell if this was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment:

> Does your `K8S manifests` is a single file with `Deployment`, `Service` and `HPA` inside of it? I ran exactly as you've pasted it (encountered same warning) and it lacked the `---` in between the resources.

Talking specifically about the content included in `Content of K8s manifests`, this file is missing three dashes `(---)` between the resources.

It could be fixed either by:

- spliting the resources in multiple files (by following `skaffold.yaml` and it's template `k8*.yml`):

  - `k8s-deployment.yaml`
  - `k8s-service.yaml`
  - `k8s-hpa.yaml`
- adding the `---` between each of the resource in `Content of K8s manifests` (example):

```
DEPLOYMENT
---
SERVICE
--- 
HPA
```

You can read more about `---` in YAML files by following this StackOverflow answer:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: why — (3 dashes/hyphen) in yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53691066/12257134)*

---

As for the reproduction. I used the the official getting started guide:

- *[Skaffold.dev: Docs: Quickstart](https://skaffold.dev/docs/quickstart/)*

I copied the `Content of K8s manifests` into the `k8s-pod.yaml` and changed the line (this file does not have `---` between the resources):

```yaml
      - image: gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp
```

Running below command with:

- `$ skaffold dev`

```sh
Listing files to watch...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp
Generating tags...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp -> gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp:<--REDACTED-->
Checking cache...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp: Not found. Building
Building [gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp]...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
<--REDACTED-->
<--REDACTED-->: Pushed 
<--REDACTED-->: Layer already exists 
<--REDACTED-->: digest: <--REDACTED--> size: 739
Tags used in deployment:
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp -> gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp:<--REDACTED-->
Starting deploy...
WARN[0023] image [gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp] is not used by the deployment 
 - horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/demoapp created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
Deployments stabilized in 198.216977ms
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
```

Focusing on:

```sh
WARN[0023] image [gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp] is not used by the deployment 
 - horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/demoapp created
```

As you can see only the `HPA` object was created. `Deployment` and `Service` was not created. It's also showing the same warning as yours.

> Running `$ kubectl apply -f k8s-pod.yaml` will yield the same results!

Editing the `k8s-pod.yaml` file to include `---` and running `$ skaffold dev` once again should produce output similar to the one below:

```sh
Listing files to watch...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp
Generating tags...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp -> gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/<--REDACTED-->
Checking cache...
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp: Not found. Building
<--REDACTED-->
<--REDACTED-->: Pushed 
<--REDACTED-->: Layer already exists 
<--REDACTED-->: digest: <--REDACTED--> size: 739
Tags used in deployment:
 - gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp -> gcr.io/PROJECT-NAME/demoapp:<--REDACTED-->
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/demoapp created
 - service/demoapp-svc created
 - horizontalpodautoscaler.autoscaling/demoapp created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/demoapp is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 5.450197785s
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
[demoapp] Hello World with ---!
[demoapp] Hello World with ---!
[demoapp] Hello World with ---!
```

As you can see above all of the resources were created, there was no warning about the deployment not using an image and also the app responded.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes: Working with objects: Kubernetes objects](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/)*